# Postgres COPY FROM file throwing unicode error while referenced character apparently not in file

Tags: python, postgresql, unicode, grep

First of all, thank you to everyone on Stack Overflow for past, present, and future help. You've all saved me from disaster (both of my own design and otherwise) too many times to count.

The present issue is part of a decision at my firm to transition from a Microsoft SQL Server 2005 database to PostgreSQL 9.4. We have been following the notes on the Postgres wiki  (https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server_to_PostgreSQL_Migration_by_Ian_Harding), and these are the steps we're following for the table in question:

1. Download table data [on Windows client]:

   ```
   bcp "Carbon.consensus.observations" out "Carbon.consensus.observations" -k -S [servername] -T -w
   ```
2. Copy to Postgres server [running CentOS 7]
3. Run Python pre-processing script on Postgres server to change encoding and clean:

   ```
   import sys
   import os
   import re
   import codecs
   import fileinput

   base_path = '/tmp/tables/'
   cleaned_path = '/tmp/tables_processed/'
   files = os.listdir(base_path)

   for filename in files:

       source_path = base_path + filename
       temp_path = '/tmp/' + filename
       target_path = cleaned_path + filename

       BLOCKSIZE = 1048576 # or some other, desired size in bytes
       with open(source_path, 'r') as source_file:
           with open(target_path, 'w') as target_file:
               start = True
               while True:
                   contents = source_file.read(BLOCKSIZE).decode('utf-16le')
                   if not contents:
                       break
                   if start:
                       if contents.startswith(codecs.BOM_UTF8.decode('utf-8')):
                           contents = contents.replace(codecs.BOM_UTF8.decode('utf-8'), ur'')
                   contents = contents.replace(ur'\x80', u'')
                   contents = re.sub(ur'\000', ur'', contents)
                   contents = re.sub(ur'\r\n', ur'\n', contents)
                   contents = re.sub(ur'\r', ur'\\r', contents)
                   target_file.write(contents.encode('utf-8'))
                   start = False

       for line in fileinput.input(target_path, inplace=1):
           if '\x80' in line:
               line = line.replace(r'\x80', '')
           sys.stdout.write(line)
   ```
4. Execute SQL to load table:

   ```
   COPY consensus.observations FROM '/tmp/tables_processed/Carbon.consensus.observations';
   ```

The issue is that the COPY command is failing with a unicode error:

```
[2015-02-24 19:52:24] [22021] ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x80
Where: COPY observations, line 2622420: "..."
```

Given that this could very likely be because of bad data in the table (which also contains legitimate non-ASCII characters), I'm trying to find the actual byte sequence in context, and I can't find it anywhere (sed to look at the line in question, regexes to replace the character as part of the preprocessing, etc). For reference, this grep returns nothing:

```
cat /tmp/tables_processed/Carbon.consensus.observations | grep --color='auto' -P "[\x80]"
```

What am I doing wrong in tracking down where this byte sequence sits in context?

Comment: Replacing the byte alone is incorrect because '\x80' is valid in UTF-8 when it is preceded by certain other bytes. It's invalid as the first byte of a sequence. Based on the error message, can you show the lines around 2622420? Try something like `tail -n+2622415 filename | head -n10 | hexdump -C`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend loading the *SQL* file (which appears to be **/tmp/tables_processed/Carbon.consensus.observations**) into an editor that has a *hex* mode. This should allow you to see it (depending on the exact editor) in context.

*gVim* (or terminal-based *Vim*) is one option I would recommend.

For example, if I open in *gVim* an *SQL* *copy* file that has this content:

```
1   1.2
2   1.1
3   3.2
```

I can the convert it into hex mode via the command `%!xxd` (in *gVim* or terminal *Vim*) or the Menu option **Tools > Convert to HEX**.

That yields this display:

```
0000000: 3109 312e 320a 3209 312e 310a 3309 332e  1.1.2.2.1.1.3.3.
0000010: 320a                                     2.
```

You can then run `%!xxd -r` to convert it back, or the Menu option **Tools > Convert back**.

**Note:** This actually modifies the file, so it would be advisable to do this to a copy of the original, just in case the changes somehow get written (you would have to explicitly save the buffer in *Vim*).

This way, you can see both the hex sequences on the left, and their *ASCII* equivalent on the right. If you search for `80`, you should be able to see it in context. With *gVim*, the line numbering will be different for both modes, though, as is evidenced by this example.

It's likely the first `80` you find will be that line, though, since if there were earlier ones, it likely would've failed on those instead.

Another tool which might help that I've used in the past is the graphical hex editor [*GHex*](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Ghex). Since that's a GNOME project, not quite sure it'll work with *CentOS*. [wxHexEditor](http://www.wxhexeditor.org/) supposedly works with *CentOS* and looks promising from the website, although I've not yet used it. It's pitched as a "hex editor for massive files", so if your *SQL* file is large, that might be the way to go.